# Repeat-fill 3D numpy array with matching planes

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have two 3D numpy arrays of large size `(~1.2b elements, e.g. 80k x 500 x 30)`.
These two arrays have the same size on 2 dimension but differ on the third, which is related to timestamps. I also have two arrays containing the timestamp values corresponding to the planes along the size differing axis. I would like to stretch/broadcast and fill the shorter array with the last plane that contained values in itself prior to the gap, in order to get to the same size as the larger array such that I can then sum them up. The "gaps" and "last plane" are determined by how the timestamp arrays match that relate to the data arrays.

Here is the logic illustrated (has black font, for dark mode version see further below):

[image]

---

### Timestamp Relationship between Arrays

Along the axis in which the arrays differ in size, the corresponding values in the timestamp arrays are dates. However, the granularity of these timestamps can vary. For example, the timestamps relating to the larger array may be a series of consecutive days, and the timestamps relating to the shorter array may be every Friday within the same period, but ending short or beginning late, i.e. missing the first 5 Fridays or the last 10 Fridays when comparing to the start and end of the larger array.

When there is such a "gap", I would like the (temproally speaking) last available plane of the 3D array to stretched over that gap until the next available plane has values.

Note, the Fridays example was just one case. It could also be that the larger array corresponds to every Monday in a certain period and the shorter array is the first day of every month in that period, but ending short or starting late.

Another important note might be that the axis of the 3D arrays relating to the timestamps has the smallest size of all the axis. Meaning for example, array 1 might be (80k, 500, 180) and array 2 might be (80k, 500, 50). So looping over that axis and then repeating planes of size (80k, 500, 1) might work. But I don't know how.

Also, the shorter array is fully contained in the larger.

### Code Example

Let's say there are two arrays A and B

```
m, k, n, v = 3, 4, 10, 4

A = np.random.randint(10, size=(m, n, k))
B = np.random.randint(10, size=(m, v, k))

A_timestamps = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
B_timestamps = [2, 4, 7, 8]
```

However, although B_timestamps is fully contained, its lowest timestamp is greater than the lowest timestamp in A. In other words, B start late.

Then the reindexing with this method

```
equals = np.equal.outer(A_timestamps, B_timestamps)
filled = np.maximum.accumulate(equals, axis=0)
reindex = len(B_timestamps) - np.argmax(filled[:, ::-1], axis=1) - 1
```

leads to

```
# array([4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int64)
```

starting with a 4.

Ideally, when reindexing the array B, I would want the gap in the front, due to B starting late, to be filled with zeros.

I guess I could check for the first matching timestamp first, only reindex B from there on, and then maybe use np.pad to add zeros at B's front to make up for the excluded timestamps in A.

---

Repeating image with white font for dark mode users:

[image]

Comment: How should stretching be done? For example, it could be done by repeating the previous observation. E.g. if array 1 has observations every 5 minutes, and array 2 has observations every 10 minutes, you could repeat each array 2 observation twice. Another way would be a linear interpolation between values.

Comment: Just added an edit to my question to clarify further

Comment: Please show a small example (~10 samples) of what you are trying to do. The conceptual diagrams are good and all, but in this case, a line of code speaks a thousand pictures

Comment: For example, what dtype are you actually working with, are all the elements of the smaller date array fully contained in the larger array? Stuff like that.

Comment: Also, things like "Edit 1" are not helpful. SO maintains an edit history for you, you don't need to emphasize that the first part of your question is incomplete. Instead, discard the parts that don't work, and update your question to the best you can make it at all times.

Comment: The shorter array is fully containted within the larger.
Will now edit to include code

Comment: Code example added

Comment: Are the larger array's timestamps at a constant width? I.e. is the gap between consecutive timestamps fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method seems to be a bit more performant than @Chrysophylaxs [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75739056/9311480), maybe ~2x for larger input.

First find the indices where `B_timestamps` would fit into `A_timestamps`. The gaps between these indices represent the number of times each element of `B` should be used:

```py
repeats = np.diff(np.searchsorted(A_timestamps, B_timestamps), append=A_timestamps[-1])
B_expanded = np.repeat(B, repeats, axis=1)
```

For the left padding with 0s:

```py
left_pad_width = A.shape[1] - B_expanded.shape[1]
B_expanded = np.pad(
    B_expanded,
    pad_width=((0, 0), (left_pad_width, 0), (0, 0)),
    constant_values=0,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it largely depends on how the timestamps look. The main trick is to generate an array of indices for your second array that has the length of the variable size axis in the first. To illustrate, let's say you had arrays `A` and `B` and something like:

```
m, k, n, v = 3, 4, 10, 5

A = np.random.randint(10, size=(m, n, k))
B = np.random.randint(10, size=(m, v, k))

A_timestamps = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
B_timestamps = [1, 2, 4, 7, 8]
```

The reindexing array for B you want would be:

```
reindex = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4] # <<< Index taken from B
#          0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9    <<< Corresponding "aligned" index in A
```

such that you could simply write:

```
out = A + B[:, reindex, :]
```

So what is the best way to create the reindexing array? I don't know... here is what I came up with, assuming unique and sorted timestamps:

```
equals = np.equal.outer(A_timestamps, B_timestamps)
filled = np.maximum.accumulate(equals, axis=0)
reindex = len(B_timestamps) - np.argmax(filled[:, ::-1], axis=1) - 1
# array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The general logic looks very promising. I'll try to implement it that way.

Comment: Good luck, I hope it works out of the box ;). I can't tell from the code you posted what the 2 timestamps array are expected to be like. If you give more info / examples on those, I might be able to help more @DattelKlauber

Comment: So the method works fine when the shorter array starts with the same timestamp as the larger. But there's a problem in the reindexing when the shorter array "starts late". I explained the problem in the code example in the original question that I just edited.

Comment: The outer product makes me think that a vanilla python while loop might be better for large size timestamp arrays.